# Who owns the copyright on a Watson recording?

Tags: copyright

If I record my own work using [IBM's Watson demo](https://text-to-speech-demo.mybluemix.net), who owns the copyright on those recordings?

I couldn't find the terms of use for the demo service, nor the full service after registration.

Answer (score 1):

Under US copyright law, the copyright of the work vests in the author of the work.  17 USC §201.

Comment: I've found [this TOS](http://www-03.ibm.com/software/sla/sladb.nsf/sla/bm-6947-04) where they talk about using the "data" to improve the service but I could't find anything referring specifically to the audio recordings like for instance with [Amazon's Polly](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/21346/286).